# new SqlFileStream fails with Integrated Security

Tags: c#, sql, filestream

I've been working up a test case for a problem with "new SqlFileStream" from a Winforms app on Windows XP, and in doing so, have run into another problem when running the testcase app on Windows 7.

In all cases, the connection string is using Integrated Security.

The call below works when run as admin, but not when run as a "mortal user":

```
using (SqlFileStream sfs = new SqlFileStream(sqlFilePath, (byte[])transactionContextParm.Value,
 SIO.FileAccess.Write))
{
//...
}
```

In all cases, a call to a stored procedure that selects from the same row used to select for the FILESTREAM works, so the user has access to the database.

And prior to making the call above, the stored procedure has successfully returned the PathName and the FileStream transaction context.

Here's the error information that is captured from the exception that's caught:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (NativeErrorCode=5/ErrorCode=0x80004005): Access is denied 
at System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlFileStream.OpenSqlFileStream(String path, Byte[] transactionContext, FileAccess access, FileOptions options, Int64 allocationSize)
at System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlFileStream..ctor(String path, Byte[] transactionContext, FileAccess access, FileOptions options, Int64 allocationSize)
at System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlFileStream..ctor(String path, Byte[] transactionContext, FileAccess access)
...
```

The code works when run on the Win 7 client machine as a user who has admin privileges on the SQL server, but not when run as a "mortal user".

In the original application (from which this test case was distilled), doesn't have this particular problem, so I've missed something about the permissions I've set up for this test case.

Any suggestions about permissions that are needed, or how to diagnose this problem would be gratefully appreciated!